# Write String to Excel Sheet using jExcel API

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I was going through this [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html) by which I can start writing to Microsoft Excel sheet. But it shows only how to write an Integer. In my case I need to write `Strings to Excel Sheet`. In that strings I have `IP Address` as well.

So below is the scenario in which it is failing because ipAddress is String with dots in between the number. And also I cannot convert that String to Integer because of dots in between the number so that is the reason I was looking for other alternative.

**So is there any other alternative to Number class below which I can use for String?**

```
addNumber(sheet, 0, j, ipAddress);


private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, Integer integer) throws WriteException,
        RowsExceededException {
    Number number;
    number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
    sheet.addCell(number);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try by using new Label() as follow

sheet.addCell(new Label(column, row, String))